# ASP.NET MVC Telerik reporting: Session is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, telerik

I have a web page with HTML5 Telerik report viewer, which should generate and show a report in the web page.

How does Telerik report viewer get data?

You create an implementation of the class ReportControllerBase, which is a class of the Telerik framework derived from ApiController.
The class you create, which in few words is simply an ApiController, is used by the report viewer to retrieve the report, or more precisely a ReportSource.

The report viewer retrieves a ReportSource, and the ReportSource retrieves data for the report.

So, inside the ReportController you istantiate a ReportSource, you configure it so that it knows where to retrieve data, and you return it.

In my case ReportSource retrieves data thanks to a method of a class called OffersCRUD.
This method, before to call a WCF service to get data from the database, must extract the username from the session, but the problem is that HttpContext.Current.Session is null.

I know that by deafault sessions are not enabled in Web api, but I wrote some lines of code to force it using sessions, which seems to work well in general.

There are two important requests during the report generation.

Request 1: ReportController is called, the ReportSource is istantiated to use OffersCRUD as datasource and then returned. **Here the session works**.

Request 2: Now that that the Report Viewer has retrieved the ReportSource, it performs an other request to obtain data, and so we are now inside the class OffersCRUD. **Here the session doesn't work, it is null.**.

So, from now I will only speak about the second request.
From the point of view of the debugger, everything starts in the following method (before this there is External code, the code which calls the method is encapsulated)

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
public static PersonOfferDTO GetPersonOfferByNumber(string offerNumber)
{
    PersonOfferDTO result = null;
    List<IError> errors = new List<IError>();
    ServiceCaller.GetDataWithServiceUsingParameter(GetPersonOffer, errors, ref result, offerNumber);

    return result;
}
```

Then, after some lines of code, we are inside the class UserSession, which is a wapper of the session.

```
    public static class UserSession
    {
            private static UserDTO _currentUser;

            public static UserDTO GetCurrentUser()
            {
                HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

                if(context.Session["UserLogin"] == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                UserDTO currentUser = context.Session["UserLogin"] as UserDTO;

                return currentUser;
            }

            public static void SaveUserStatus(UserDTO user)
            {
                Validate.EnsureArgumentIsNotNull(user);

                HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                context.Session["UserLogin"] = user;
            }

   }
```

In the method UserDTO GetCurrentUser(void), the state of HttpContext.Current is what you can see in the picture below.

[image]

As you can see, Session is null, so it will fail when it will try to access Session["UserLogin"].

If you want more details you only have to write a comment here below.

Comment: Depending on `HttpContext.Current.Session` in a Web API seems like a very bad approach. Question is who/how is this custom ApiController called?

Comment: Telerik report viewer is supposed to use web api. I would use a simple MVC controller but I can't.

Comment: OK, can you provide more details about how this report viewer calls into the controller? Is this some javascript component that makes an AJAX request or is it implemented differently? Somehow a request needs to be done. Once we understand how this request is made we could see what options are available to send back the session cookie.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I can't explain exactly how it works because the operation of the report viewer is encapsulated. By the way yes, it seems that the request is done with AJAX. In the request header I see this: X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Telerik Report => Start Process in Background Thread => UI => Load processed report from Background Thread

The background thread does not have access to the current context and the current session.

You also tightly coupled your business logic to the ASP.NET session object.

You could try a regular MVC Controller/Action instead of WebAPI, but if its called in a background thread and does not pass browser cookies then it would not have knowledge of the current session.

You could try to set the username/password as report parameters, and then pass those into your webservice in the NeedsDataSource event.

Or if its a known report, you could load and attach the data to a public property on the report and bind it in the NeedsDataSource event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please, note that I'm able to access the session in ReportController. The problem with the session occurs ONLY inside the data source object (OffersCRUD). Also note that the problem is not only that the session is null, but HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance is null too and many properties of HttpContext.Current throw a null reference exception (you can see the state of HttpContext.Current in the picture).
That said, are you saying that the Telerik report viewer always uses a background thread and so I can do nothing to access the session?

Comment: The report is created in the current thread, but processing happens in a background thread.  That's how you get the loading spinner.  Telerik UI passes two GUID to load the report in an IFrame, the renderID indicates the client browser, and the instanceID is the report instance that is being processed and is stored in HttpRuntime.Cache.   The report is processed once, but multiple renderers can be invoked without having to reprocess the report (Export as Word, PDF, RTF).  You will have to decouple your session dependency in your business layer (think TDD outside of ASP.NET)

Answer (score 0):

Session is not enabled in Web Api because it does not respect REST based design. As Telerik tries to fit with this design, they do not recommend to use session with Telerik Report Viewer.

You should use an [ObjectDataSource](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/objectdatasource.html) component instead to pass data to the report. In this object, you can wrap a method to retrieve data, with your custom logic (but without session).

Comment: I know that WEB API don't use sessions by default. I wrote some lines of code to enable sessions and it works, because I can access the session correctly in other requests inside the same WEB API. 
By the way when sessions are not enabled you simply have a null reference for HttpContext.Current.Session. If you look at the state of HttpContext.Current in the picture you will see that many things are broken: it's not only that session is null.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issue today. Found the solution in Telerik knowledge base. Here it goes..

Taken from here https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/how-to-pass-information-from-httpcontext-to-reporting-engine

From Telerik Product Version 12.1 18.620
To access the current user context, you can use the Telerik.Reporting.Processing.UserIdentity.Current static property. It is also possible to use the new UserIdentity object in the expression context as a global object: =UserIdentity.

With the changes introduced in Telerik Reporting 12.1.18.620 it is possible to use the UserIdentity.Context property to store user objects (for example from the HttpContext). UserIdentity.Context can be filled up with the needed values in the ReportsController by overriding the GetUserIdentity() method. Here is a sample code :

```
// include in the ReportsController class

protected override UserIdentity GetUserIdentity()
{
    var identity = base.GetUserIdentity();
    identity.Context = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
    identity.Context["UrlReferrer"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;

    // Any other available information can be stored in the identity.Context in the same way

    return identity;
}
```

The UserIdentity.Current.Context["UrlRefferer"] should then be used (instead of HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer) to access the corresponding property/information. For example, you can access the UrlRefferer as :

```
// can be included in the Resolve() method of the Custom Report Resolver
Uri urlReferrer = (Uri)UserIdentity.Current.Context["UrlRefferer"];
```